# Why does running numpy (array substraction) in diferent process is so slow (compare to single process) even if multithreading is deactivated

Tags: python, numpy, performance, process

Given the following script:

```py
#!python

import os
import time

os.environ["OMP_NUM_THREADS"] = "1"
os.environ["MKL_NUM_THREADS"] = "1"
os.environ["OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS"] = "1"
os.environ["VECLIB_MAXIMUM_THREADS"] = "1"
os.environ["NUMEXPR_NUM_THREADS"] = "1"

import numpy

a = numpy.zeros((100000, 512))
b = numpy.ones((100000, 512))

t0 = time.time()
for _ in range(100):
    a - b
print(f"Ellapsed time: {time.time()-t0:.2f}")
```

If I execute it once, I can ensure that only one thread is running at the same time, and I got:

```
$> ./benchmark_numpy.py
Ellapsed time: 6.80
```

But if I do:

```
$> for i in {1..4}     
do
./benchmark_numpy.py&
done
[2] 253122
[3] 253123
[4] 253124
[5] 253125

---

$> [5]  + 253125 done       ./benchmark_numpy.py
Ellapsed time: 17.15
$> [3]  - 253123 done       ./benchmark_numpy.py
Ellapsed time: 17.16
$> [4]  + 253124 done       ./benchmark_numpy.py
Ellapsed time: 17.22
$> [2]  + 253122 done       ./benchmark_numpy.py
Ellapsed time: 17.23
```

There is no pickling no shared stuff that could be locked or whatever, They do are only 4 threads running at the same time, but still, it is almost 3 times longer.

I just don't understand, what could be the reason of this ?

Answer (score 0):

The probleme was that my CPU (intel) enabled the Turbo mode when i'was using only one process.